# Strongly-typed dataset not retrieving return value from stored procedure

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, ado.net, strongly-typed-dataset

I have a strongly-typed dataset that is using DBDirectMethods to insert data into a database using calls to stored procedures. The stored procedures return the primary key of the newly-created record. Here's a sample stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.CreateUser
(
    @UserName   VARCHAR(50)
    @Password   VARCHAR(50)
)
AS

SET NOCOUNT OFF

DECLARE @UserID INT

BEGIN TRANSACTION

INSERT INTO dbo.Users (UserName, Password) VALUES (@UserName, @Password)

SET @UserID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

INSERT INTO dbo.Users_History (UserID, Status, TimeStamp) VALUES (@UserID, 'C', GETUTCDATE())

COMMIT TRANSACTION

RETURN @UserID

GO
```

If I execute the stored procedure from SSMS, then the user account is created, the history table updated, and the primary key returned. If I run my application using the strongly-typed dataset and have SQL Profiler ticking away, I can see the same code being executed; however, the dataset returns -1 as the primary key and breaks the app.

Inside the VS-generated code for the table adapter, the relevant lines are:

```
this._adapter.InsertCommand.CommandText = "dbo.CreateUser";
this._adapter.InsertCommand.CommandType = global::System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
this._adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@RETURN_VALUE", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 4, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.ReturnValue, 10, 0, null, global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Current, false, null, "", "", ""));
this._adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@UserName", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 0, 0, "UserName", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Current, false, null, "", "", ""));
this._adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@Password", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 0, 0, "Password", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Current, false, null, "", "", ""));
```

and

```
try {
    int returnValue = this.Adapter.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    return returnValue;
}
finally {
    if ((previousConnectionState == global::System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)) {
        this.Adapter.InsertCommand.Connection.Close();
    }
}
```

which is all just the standard boiler-plate code that VS usually generates - nothing has been edited by hand. It just doesn't pick up the return value.

I am running Windows 7 with SQL 2008 R2 SP1 Express.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From memory, the issue here is that the value [ExecuteNonQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx)() returns is the number of rows affected by the query.

Instead, your return value should be accessible via:

```
InsertCommand.Parameters["@RETURN_VALUE"].Value;
```

or

```
InsertCommand.Parameters[0].Value;
```

In addition, you can try changing your return parameter name to `@UserID` rather than `@RETURN_VALUE` but it should still work as you have it.

Comment: The setting up of the return value is taken care of by the generated code, and if I remove the SET NOCOUNT ON from my stored procedure, that value correctly loads the number of affected rows (i.e. 2); but if I try to return any other value, then it fails. I've worked out a solution though (see below).

Comment: The return value is in the parameter - this is a weakness of the autogenerated code - it doesn't really care about output and return parameters. Your solution is probably the best one if you want to rely on the autogenerated code alone.

Comment: ExecuteScalar does seem to be the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that rather than returning only the PK, I need to return the entire new record. By changing my stored procedure to the following:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.CreateUser
(
    @UserName   VARCHAR(50)
    @Password   VARCHAR(50)
)
AS

SET NOCOUNT OFF

DECLARE @UserID INT

BEGIN TRANSACTION

INSERT INTO dbo.Users (UserName, Password) VALUES (@UserName, @Password)

SET @UserID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

INSERT INTO dbo.Users_History (UserID, Status, TimeStamp) VALUES (@UserID, 'C', GETUTCDATE())

COMMIT TRANSACTION

SELECT UserID, UserName, Password FROM dbo.Users WHERE UserID = @UserID

GO
```

then ADO.NET automatically loads the returned result into the dataset, and I can get UserID from there.

Comment: Note you could also do SELECT UserID, then, instead of ExecuteNonQuery, you can do ExecuteScalar and cast the result to an Int32. - e.g. int userId = Convert.ToInt32(Adapter.InsertCommand.ExecuteScalar());

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the query type from ExecuteNonQuery to ExecuteScalar
See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/smartclientdata/archive/2005/10/31/returnidentityvaluequery.aspx